# View archive image file

Tags: c#, image, zip

Can I view an image (thumbnail) from a .zip file in a PictureBox using C# without extracting the .zip?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract a single file from a .ZIP into a memory stream. [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) is one library that can do it.

Here is a sample from their Examples page:

```
using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
{
    ZipEntry e = zip["Image.bmp"];
    e.Extract(outputStream);
}
```

You now have the image in a stream, which you can use to set the source of your `PictureBox`:

```
var bmp = new Bitmap(outputStream);
pictureBox.Image = bmp;
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't do this without extracting the image from the zip. You don't necessarily need to extract it into a temporary file, you could extract it into a memory stream and then create an image from that stream.

Comment: How Microsoft displays the thumbnail of an office template that is actually in the archive (template)? Every time I select a PowerPoint template to preview it the power point template file is extracted?

Comment: First of all, PowerPoint is native code, not .NET. Second, it is not necessary to extract the entire contents of the .ZIP to get the contents of a single file in the .ZIP. Third, the thumbnail file in the .ZIP must be "extracted" (decompressed) in order to render it. Office may decompress the single file to a temp folder or directly in memory, as suggested by @Cornel.